# partial order - finite set - minimal element

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, poset

**Prove by induction**.Every **partial order** on a **nonempty finite** set at least one **minimal** element.

How can **I**  solve that question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the partial order has size 1, it is obvious.

Assume it is true for partial orders `<n`, and then take a partial order `(P,<)` has size `n`.

Pick `x` in `P`.  Let `P(<x) = { y in P : y<x }`

If `P(<x)` is empty, then `x` is a minimal element.

Otherwise,  `P(<x)` is strictly smaller than `P`, since `x` is not in `P(<x)`.  So the poset `(P(<x),<)`
must have a minimal element, `y`.

This `y` must be a minimal element of `P` since, if `z<y` in `P`, then `z<x`, and hence `z` would be in `P(<x)` and smaller than `y`, which contradicts the assumption that `y` was minimal in `P(<x)`.

Answer (score 2):

It is trivially true if there is only one element in the poset. Now suppose it is true for all sets of size < n. Compare the nth element to the minimal element of the (n-1) poset, which we know to exist. It will either be the new minimal or not or incomparable. It doesn't matter either way. (Why?)